# GitHub Pages Precedence

Tags: github, github-pages

Say I have the following repositories on GitHub:

```
caffinatedmonkey (user)
│
├── caffinatedmonkey.github.io
│   └── tree
│       └── master
│           └── foo
│               └── index.html
└── foo
    └── tree
        ├── master
        └── gh-pages
            └── index.html
```

If I go to [caffinatedmonkey.github.io/foo](http://caffinatedmonkey.github.io/foo), which page will be shown? Which page takes precedence, the project page, `https://github.com/caffinatedmonkey/foo/tree/gh-pages/index.html` or the user page, `https://github.com/caffinatedmonkey/caffinatedmonkey.github.io/tree/master/foo/index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a test by replicating the repository structure in the question. When I visited [`caffinatedmonkey.github.io/foo`](http://caffinatedmonkey.github.io/foo) I was taken to the user's foo page, `https://github.com/caffinatedmonkey/caffinatedmonkey.github.io/tree/master/foo/index.html`.

User pages take precedence.

Answer (score 3):

User pages "take precedence", but not in a per url basis. Even if the urls don't collide, having a user page disables project pages.

In order to work arround this you can have the gh-pages branch of a project page set up as a submodule of your `user.github.io` repo.

```
cd user.github.io
git submodule add -b gh-pages https://github.com/user/project.git
git submodule update
git commit -m 'Added submodule for project'
git push
```